# can we squash the latest commit to a specific previous commit?

Tags: git, version-control, squash, git-squash

For example, if we want to squash the commit at `HEAD` into commit `HEAD~4`, we have an option by which we can do so by

1. resetting commits from `HEAD` to `HEAD~3`
2. building a temporary commit with same changes as our old HEAD(say, `temp`)
3. stashing other staged/unstaged changes
4. squashing `temp` with our old `HEAD~4`
5. popping our stashed changes
6. building commits again as older commits(`HEAD~3` to `HEAD`).

is there any other faster and convenient way of doing the same?

Comment: [git rebase has an "autosquash" feature](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+rebase+autosquash) for this

Comment: i didn't think it could be this convenient... OMG! that made my life a hell lot easier!!!! thanks @jthill and stack overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so as @jthill suggested, there exists an `autosquash` option for git.

for example, in my case, let initial case be,

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate
ddd4444 (HEAD, my-feature-branch) A fourth commit
ccc3333 A third commit
bbb2222 A second commit
aaa1111 A first commit
9999999 (master) Old stuff on master
```

I would now add the recent changes which i wanted to squash with `HEAD~4`
as:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit --fixup aaa1111
[my-feature-branch eee5555] fixup! A first commit
```

so, my history now looks like:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate
eee5555 (HEAD, my-feature-branch) fixup! A first commit
ddd4444 A fourth commit
ccc3333 A third commit
bbb2222 A second commit
aaa1111 A first commit
9999999 (master) Old stuff on master
```

now rebasing using `autosquash` by `$ git rebase --interactive --autosquash master` gives automatically picked commits with `--fixup` commit at the correct place.

Following the rebase and merge with commit-message edits, you will have the commit rebased successfully!

works like magic! :)

source: [thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/autosquashing-git-commits)